# MKMapView: image is blocked when fully zoomed into the mapview

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, zooming

After zooming in completely into the MKMapView, it presents me with the image below.  Why is this happening, and how can it be fixed?

[image: click here to see the image]

Comment: I recall seeing that every now and then while the map is trying to render, and it typically appears after some delay, have you tried waiting a bit?

Comment: Hi Himphrey, How did you fixed this issue?